# BIM 360 - API - All communications to specified mailbox

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am looking for is something that will automatically forward a copy of ALL emails generated from BIM 360 to be CC’d to this specific email address.

For example a document shares’ should be sent as normal but in the background the system automatically also sends the share email to the Group email address for record.

Another example would be a BIM 360 Review that is issued to 12 reviewers. The emails being sent to notify reviewer and those going to the initiator should be CC’d to the group email without user interaction.

Is there any api that can do that?

Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find tools, software libraries or other off-site resources are off-topic. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting, as was suggested when you created your account here.

Answer (score 0):

No API to cc/bcc e-mails from BIM 360 products.

One thing you may be able to do is to watch file operations related event using webhooks API with Data management API:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/developers_guide/overview/

here is a sample application on gihub:
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360notifier

Comment: It looks promising. I will try that route. cheers